# How can I get current date in c++?

Tags: c++, date, ctime

I did not find any solution which give the only date. I found the solution but all are complex and we have to parse the array and separate the date from time

Answer (score 2):

Try to this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    auto t = std::time(nullptr);
    auto tm = *std::localtime(&t);
    std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S") << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run the following code, today then you will find the 
current date in following format.

04/14/15

```html
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 char c[9];
 _strdate_s(c);
 cout<<c<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code snippets doesn't support c++, yet.

Comment: _strdate_s is not a function included in the c++ standard. it is only supported by the library shipped with visual studio as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

[ideone code](http://ideone.com/YCD3uN)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    time_t now = time(0);

   tm *ltm = localtime(&now);

   cout << "Year: "<< 1900 + ltm->tm_year << endl;
   cout << "Month: "<< 1 + ltm->tm_mon<< endl;
   cout << "Day: "<<  ltm->tm_mday << endl;
}
```